# Virtualkeyboard Adjust pan issue in phonegap

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm developing a phonegap application using JQM,i'm facing a problem when the virtual keyboard appears when entering the values for the fields, the fields are getting hide when the virtual keyboard appears.

I had changed the android Manifest XML file for adjusting the virtual keyboard,as below

```
<activity android:name="com.cliniqbase.cliniqbase.MainActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
```

and in the html page i had added the following in the meta tag as below,

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
```

Any one facing the same problem ?

Please suggest solution for fixing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is been fixed, when i removed fullscreen mode from my app, the adjustPan had worked fine.

AdjsutPan won't work properly in fullscreen mode of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the `oncreate` of `mainactivity`:

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```